# Changing all the file names in a folder to something else Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

For python, I am writing code that uses `os.rename()` to rename files

What I have so far:

```
[os.rename(f, f.replace('New', '-'))
    for f in os.listdir('.') if not f.startswith('.')]
```

What I am trying to do is from `C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\pythonVSC` to look into  `C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\pythonVSC\forTest` and to change all cases of `New` to `-`

in `forTest` I have two `.txt` files names `New` and `New_`

I understand what `.replace` does and what `.listdir` does and also `.startwith` does.

My issue is that if I change the `'.'` in `os.listdir('.')` the for statement  to `'./somePath'` I get the error as seen below

```
Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'New.txt' -> '-.txt'
  File "C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\pythonVSC\rename.py", line 29, in <listcomp>
    [os.rename(f, f.replace('New', '-')) for f in os.listdir('./forTest') if not f.startswith('.')]
  File "C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\pythonVSC\rename.py", line 29, in <module>
    [os.rename(f, f.replace('New', '-')) for f in os.listdir('./forTest') if not f.startswith('.')]
```

I tried replacing `os.listdir('.')` with `os.listdir('forTest')`, `os.listdir('C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\pythonVSC\forTest')` and any other variation of that

What am I doing incorrectly here?

Comment: `os.listdir('./somePath')` is going to return `['New.txt', …]`, not `['./somePath/New.txt', …]`. Names of the files. You need to add the same path to both arguments of `os.rename`.

Comment: @Ry- if I put `New.txt` and `New_.txt` in `C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\pythonVSC` instead of `C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\pythonVSC\forTest` it will work perfectly fine with `os.listdir('.')`

Comment: Yes, because the paths you pass into `os.rename` are already relative to `.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files you're referring to are in another directory, but `os.rename` doesn't know that.

The simplest solution is to just change to the other directory:

```
os.chdir('./forTest')
[os.rename(f, f.replace('New', '-')) for f in os.listdir('.') if not f.startswith('.')]
```

Or, less simply, pass the full paths:

```
dirname = './forTest'
for f in os.listdir(dirname):
    if f.startswith('.'):
        continue
    f_new = f.replace('New', '-')
    os.rename(*(os.path.join(dirname, fname) for fname in (f, f_new)))
```

Comment: @Glenville Welcome! If my answer was the most helpful, please click the check mark to accept it.

Comment: just did! got the enough "points" to finally do so after this post

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're expecting `os.listdir()` to give you a list of absolute paths, but it actually gives you just the names (basename) of the files/dirs.
OTOH `os.rename()` needs a path to the file. The particular case of passing just the name of the file to `os.rename()` will only work if your current working directory is the same as the file you are trying to rename.